# Constructor of thread class getting called by mistake

Tags: .net, multithreading, destructor

I have a ThreadClass initaled like this

```
ThreadClass t = new ThreadClass();
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.Run));
thread.Start();
```

My ThreadClass has a destructor:

```
~ThreadClass(){ // some stuff }
```

This destructor is getting called "by mistake". This means the thread is still running and is working correctly. But the destructor is called in a unpredictable manner. It's not really reproducable, but if I set a breakpoint and run my code for long time, suddenly the destructor is getting called. Is there a garbage collection cleaning up my ThreadClass. But if so, why is my Thread continue running?

Comment: You should not use destructors.

Answer (score 1):

The GC will collect an object some time after the last reference goes out of scope.

If your `Run()` method doesn't use `this`, your instance can be collected at any time.
`GC.KeepAlive()` can change this behavior; read its documentation *carefully*.

This is why you should not use finalizers for anything other than cleaning up native resources.

Comment: *If your Run() method doesn't use this, your instance can be collected at any time.* I believe this is true only for instances kept as local variables, not for instances in which a method of it is being executed by Thread(as threads are roots). That's not the case here. I might be wrong, correct me if I am.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Reading more carefully, it looks like the `Thread` instance itself should root the instance via its delegate.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,141.  So I'm not sure.

Comment: Wow! So you are saying only the elements of the ThreadClass will be kept, which are still referenced (all instance variables and functions wich are used by the Run()-Method). The instance of the class itself is disposed?

Comment: @StefanVogel: No.  Fields are members of `this`.  If you use any member, you're actually accessing `this`.  You need to learn more about how the references and the GC work before you can reason about finalizers and object lifetimes.